# Resources to help conduct a log linear (logit) model in spss

Tags: logistic, log-linear

Does anyone know of any resource about how to conduct a loglinear (logit) analysis in spss? There are some youtube videos but not specifically about the logit one.

Comment: Loglinear and logit are quite different models.

Comment: @NickCox I understand that loglinear model analysis has three types in spss, 'logit' is one of them.

Comment: SPSS designers seemingly don’t understand statistical modeling very well….

Comment: @NickCox could be that I'm just confused haha

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the option for the logit model under:

Analyze > loglinear > Logit

Specify your dependent variable and independent variables. The dependent variable should be a binary variable for a logit model.

If you have a dependent variable with more than 2 categories, you have to apply a Multinomial Logit model.

Comment: Thank you! I worry about the interpretation of the results as no tutorials on this. Saw an example of a logit loglinear in a paper; the write up is similar to anova - main effects, interactions and the degree to which one factor is differentially effective at each level of a second factor. Is this true? Just trying to avoid binary logistic regression which is so underwhelming - it only predicts which IV explains the DV the best and does not look at interactions between the factors etc. My research is about whether 'gender' and 'image type' affected altruistic responses (Yes, No)

Comment: Coefficients of the logit model show the effects on log-odds which may not be much useful to you. But logit allows you to predict probabilities and marginal effects after that estimation. You are not limited to just the estimation output. The marginal effects will allow you to understand the effects of each variable, by keeping the other independent variables constant or at a specific value of your choice. You can also predict the probabilities of each outcome.

Comment: I don't think SPSS provides options to estimate marginal effects. But, you can use other software for that purpose. If you have access to STATA, it is very easy to estimate marginal effects after logit. You can also use R, it's free software.